# Kafka : enable-auto-commit property value with @RetryableTopic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am setting up ErrorHandling mechanism in my kafka consumer and trying to implement non-blocking retry mechanims via @RetryableTopuc . In this case, should the value of my below property be true or false ?

<sup><sub>spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit</sub></sup>

I am not sure what should the correct config be .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.